# Duplicate entries for @OneToOne entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple parent-child relation.

Problem: in my database there are sometimes multiple child elements that map to the same parent.

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity {
    @Id
    private long id;

    //assume every person can only have one car
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private CarEntity car;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class CarEntity {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_person_id", foreignkey = @ForeignKey("name = "fk_person"))
    private PersonEntity person;

    private String name;
}
```

Question: how can I happen that there are multiple `car` elements that map to the *same* person entity? How is it even possible that hibernate persists those elements? And where could they come from?

As a result, when I fetch those person entities having multiple car mappings, I'm getting of course an exception:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 123, for class: CarEntity...`

Sidenote: I would finally want to delete the duplicate `CarEntity` and only keep the most recent one. But how can I prevent this to happen in future?

Update:

```
@Transactional
public PersonEntity createUpdatePerson(PersonDTO dto) {
    PersonEntity entity = dao.findByPersonName(dto.getName); //CrudRepository by spring
    if (entity == null) {
        entity = new Person();
    }

    mergeDTO(dto, entity); //copy and fill new values
    if (person.getId() == null) dao.save(entity);
    return entity;
}

private void mergeDTO(PersonDTO dto, PersonEntity entity) {
       if (dto.getCar() != null) {
             if (entity.getCar() == null) entity.setCar(new Car());
             entity.getCar().setName(dto.getCar().getName());
             entity.getCar().setPerson(entity);
       }
}
```

Comment: your database data is filled only via java-app with hibernate??

Comment: could id be when  you update a person and you persist the entity it creates an new car for it

Comment: Yes I'm only using java hibernate, with `spring` as layer. And no, I'm wrapping the save/update call in a `@Transactional` method so I'm not regenerating the entity.

Comment: It's impossible to have this error if your DB generated by entity with hibernate

Comment: can you please post your dao method??

Comment: @Abdelhak again, agree!! but `@OneToMany` wont resolve the problem... We must find where the configuration or DAO methods are making the mistake....

Comment: Firstly, post the relevant code: that is where you create/save. Secondly, add a unique index to the DB then at least you will get an exception on duplicate which may help identify this issue. Thirdly, turn on SQL logging.

Comment: Added the simple dao method above. I have no unique index so far. I could add it, but I wonder why hibernate saved duplicates?

Comment: You miss the return statrement

Comment: What about the merge method? You are asking about duplicate cars but show no code in this area. Show **all** the relevant code

Comment: Added also the merge method.

Comment: were you able to solve this? I have the same problem